# Add two dynamic checkout buttons on product page in Shopify?

Tags: shopify

I am new to Shopify and need to add two dynamic checkout buttons on product page.
That is, add one dynamic checkout button just above product description section and another dynamic checkout button just below product description section.

Is it possible to do this?
If so, how to add this?

I tried to add dynamic checkout button using the following code snippet:

`{{ form | payment_button }}`

So I added this code snippet inside "Add To Cart" form section and duplicated this form just below of product description section.
It worked like a charm for first section (above product description), but it didn't create buttons for second section (below product description).

I am not sure how to implement this feature.
Any advice would be much appreciated.